# How to fill cell by cell of an empty pandas dataframe which has zero columns with a loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to scrape hundreds of pages and instead of storing the whole json of each page, I want to just store several columns from each page into a pandas dataframe. However, at the beginning when the dataframe is empty, I have a problem. I need to fill an empty dataframe without any columns or rows. So the loop below is not working correctly:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests


cids = [4100,4101,4102,4103,4104]
df = pd.DataFrame()

for i in cids:
    url_info = requests.get(f'myurl/{i}/profile')
    jdata = url_info.json()
    df['Customer_id'] = i
    df['Name'] = jdata['user']['profile']['Name']
    ...
```

In this case, what should I do?

Comment: If the columns will always be the same, then you can add your columns to your empty df, and append new values in each for loop iteration.

Comment: I have done this, but it is not working. For instance just you use a for loop to fill an empty df as below:
`df = pd.DataFrame()
 for i in cids:
      df['Customer_id'] = i`
This is not working!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this by using [`enumerate()`](https://realpython.com/python-enumerate/), together with [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```py
for index, i in enumerate(cids):
    url_info = requests.get(f'myurl/{i}/profile')
    jdata = url_info.json()
    df.loc[index, 'Customer_id'] = i
    df.loc[index, 'Name'] = jdata['user']['profile']['Name']
```

Answer (score 2):

If you specify your column names when you create your empty dataframe, as follows:
`df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Customer_id', 'Name'])`
Then you can then just append your new data using:
`df = df.append({'Customer_id' : i, 'Name' : jdata['user']['profile']['Name']}, ignore_index=True)`
(plus any other columns you populate) then you can add a row to the dataframe for each iteration of your for loop.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests


cids = [4100,4101,4102,4103,4104]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Customer_id', 'Name'])

for i in cids:
    url_info = requests.get(f'myurl/{i}/profile')
    jdata = url_info.json()
    df = df.append({'Customer_id' : i, 'Name' : jdata['user']['profile']['Name']}, ignore_index=True)
```

It should be noted that using append on a DataFrame in a loop is usually inefficient (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36489724/14463396)) so a better way is to save your results as a list of lists (df_data), and then turn that into a DataFrame, as below:

```
cids = [4100,4101,4102,4103,4104]
df_data = []

for i in cids:
    url_info = requests.get(f'myurl/{i}/profile')
    jdata = url_info.json()
    df_data.append([i, jdata['user']['profile']['Name']])
    
df = pd.DataFrame(df_data, columns = ['Customer_id', 'Name'])
```